# Who invented modern bookends? (both model T and model L)

Tags: everyday-life, book, inventions

In ancient times the bookends were made from very heavy materials to sustain the weight of the books, while the modern ones use a smarter technique: while they are light, they are shaped so that they can use the weight of the books themselves to anchor and sustain them. I call these "model T" and "model L", depending on their shape (resembling a T or an L).

I wasn't able to find much about their history, especially who invented these models and when: both wikipedia and [another source](http://www.dimensionsinfo.com/bookends-sizes/) vaguely claim that "it was patented in 1870s", but don't bother to say who patented that, which is the exact year, and if the model was T or L or a generic patent encompassing both.

Does someone have more information about that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Be it known that I, WILLIAM STEBBINS BARNARD, of Canton, county of
>   Fulton and State of Illinois, have invented a Book-Support, of which
>   the following is a specification [of] this invention [that] relates to a support
>   or holder for books, engravings, photographs, cards, and other things,
>   which it is desired to stand on edge, and retain upright on flat
>   surfaces, as on tables, shelves, &c. The invention consists in a book
>   support or holder composed of two unconnected angular end pieces to be
>   placed at the two extremities of the row of books to be kept upright,
>   each being adapted to receive and to be held in position by the books
>   set upon its horizontal extension or base, and to support, by its
>   vertical extension or side piece, the outermost volume at its end of
>   the row, being freely movable toward or away from its fellow, in order
>   to accommodate the support or holder to. any number of books.

[Patent US 186974 A](http://www.google.com/patents/US186974), "Improvement in book-supports", published Feb 6, 1877. (So we've missed "Book End Invention Day" this year - mark it on the calendar for next!)

It's amazing how many elaborate and complicated book shelving solutions were patented before this elegant and simple solution showed up.

Comment: @Lohoris - Doing a bit more googling, and he was apparently a professor of entomology who was looking for a better way to store his specimen collection!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed he was a professor, I found a list of (some) of his publications. Nice idea to add such a comment! : )